# Binary string to hex

Tags: go

I have a string with 128 values like `011100010...`. I would like to convert this to a hex string. What I found was the other direction:

```
func partHexToBin(s string) string {
    ui, err := strconv.ParseUint(s, 16, 8)
    if err != nil {
        return ""
    }

    return fmt.Sprintf("%016b", ui)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the exact same thing the other way, since `ParseInt` allows you to pass the base of the number (decimal, hexadecimal, binary, etc.)

> ParseInt interprets a string s in the given base (0, 2 to 36) and bit size (0 to 64) and returns the corresponding value i.

Then, once you changed the base in the `ParseUint` call from 16 to 2, you'll need to change your `Sprintf` call to print the number to hexadecimal, using the `%x` format flag.

Please note however that using `ParseUint` followed by a call to `Sprintf` might not be the most performant solution.

See this example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func parseBinToHex(s string) string {
    ui, err := strconv.ParseUint(s, 2, 64)
    if err != nil {
        return "error"
    }

    return fmt.Sprintf("%x", ui)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(parseBinToHex("11101"))
}
```

Output gives

`1d`

Feel free to play around with it on the [Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/d7yDh1byOm8)

Comment: It works! One question though? What does the `64` represent in `strconv.ParseUint(s, 2, 64)`?

Comment: it represents the bit size: The bitSize argument specifies the integer type that the result must fit into. Bit sizes 0, 8, 16, 32, and 64 correspond to int, int8, int16, int32, and int64. For a bitSize below 0 or above 64 an error is returned.

Comment: Basically if your bitsize is 8 the biggest number that can fit is 256

Comment: What is the longest value `s` can have? I want `s` to have 128 values.

Comment: Quote from my answer: `bit size (0 to 64)`